# Flutter App Issue with Json Decode - Data from Socket

Tags: python, json, flutter, sockets, dart

A Short explanation about my App. I get data from a socket server which is written in python, the data are in Json Format.
When the data arrive i use Json Decode to convert it to a List. This list i use for a Listview builder to display the data. So far so good, but my problem is, that sometimes i get an Exception ([ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character)
I dont understand why sometimes everthing works perfect and sometimes i get this Error. If i use a real device this error comes more often

My Flutter Code to get the data

```
void getData({String ip, String port, String code}) async{
String result;

await Socket.connect(ip, int.parse(port)).then((socket) async {
  print('Connected to: '
      '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');
  socket.listen((data) {
      result = String.fromCharCodes(data);
  }, onDone: () {
    print("Done");
    setState(() {
      data = json.decode(result);
    });
    print (data);
  });
  socket.write(code);
});
}
```

Python Socket Server:

```
from datetime import datetime
import socket
from SqlServerRequest import SqlServerRequest


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.43.126', 4567))
s.listen(5)



while True:
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
data = clientsocket.recv(2048).decode()
print(data)

if data == "open":
    o = SqlServerRequest.dataForOpenOrders()
    clientsocket.sendall(bytes(o,"utf-8"))
if data == "closed":
    c = SqlServerRequest.dataForClosedOrders()
    clientsocket.sendall(bytes(c,"utf-8"))

clientsocket.close()
```

And the Class where i am encode the data in python

```
    def dataForClosedOrders():
    try:
        conn = odbc.connect(conn_string)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('task is terminated')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

    read_statement = "SELECT Bestelldatum, Adresse, Total, AuftragNr, ZahlungsArt, Quelle, Telefon, dauer_lieferung, zpkt_ausgeliefert, Benutzer FROM Auftrag WHERE Bestelldatum > '2021-21-04' AND Bestelldatum < '2021-22-04' AND Abholung = '0' ORDER BY Bestelldatum ASC;"
    

    cursor.execute(read_statement) 

    rows = cursor.fetchall() 
    objects_list = []
    for row in rows:
        d= collections.OrderedDict()
        d["Bestelldatum"]= row[0].strftime("%H:%M")
        a = json.loads(row[1])
        d["Adresse"] = a["str"]
        d["Tor"] = a["tor"]
        d["Stiege"] = a["stg"]
        d["Stock"] = a["stk"] 
        d["Tür"] = a["tür"]
        d["PLZ"] = a["plz"]
        d["Total"] = row[2]
        d["AuftragNr"]= row[3]
        d["ZahlungsArt"]= row[4]
        d["Quelle"]= row[5]
        d["Telefon"]= row[6]
        d["dauer_lieferung"]= row[7]
        if row[8]== None:
            d["Lieferdauer"]="nicht möglich"
        else:
            zs = row[8]-row[0]
            minutessince = int(zs.total_seconds() / 60)
            d["Lieferdauer"]=minutessince
        d["Benutzer"]= row[9]
        objects_list.append(d)
    j = json.dumps(objects_list)
    #print (j)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return j
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siY9P.png)

Sometimes works like i said

[Scrennshot from device when is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFR4a.png)

Comment: You're getting error in your json format it should be `"k":"..."` but its `k":"..."` which is an invalid key. There is no `"` before `k` key it need to be like this `"k":"...",`

Comment: No, that just a snipped, that's just the last character of a word. And sometimes is a other. And it not explain why sometimes works

Comment: `socket
.transform(json.fuse(utf8).decoder)
.listen((event) {
print(event);
});`

Comment: @pskink i tried your code, i get an error for (json.fuse(utf8).decoder) Error:  The arrgument type Converter<List<int> Object> cant be assigned to the parameter type StreamTransformer <Uint8List, dynamic>

Comment: @pskink check my edit, no i cant compile it

Comment: add `cast` - so it starts with: `socket .cast<List<int>>() .transform( ......`

Comment: @pskink It works perfect, thank you very much. I dont understand the difference but it doesnt mutter for now. Post your solution as answer, maybe someone else will have the same issue

Comment: write a self answer then... ;-)

Comment: i will, thank you again

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: no, first or single is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks pskink i find a solution.

i changed my code from

```
await Socket.connect(ip, int.parse(port)).then((socket) async {
print('Connected to: '
  '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');
socket.listen((data) {
  result = String.fromCharCodes(data);
}, onDone: () {
print("Done");
setState(() {
  data = json.decode(result);
});
print (data);
});
socket.write(code);
});
}
```

to

```
await Socket.connect(ip, int.parse(port)).then((socket) async {
  print('Connected to: '
      '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');
  socket.cast<List<int>>().transform(json.fuse(utf8).decoder).listen((event) {
    setState(() {
      data = event;
    });
  });
```

That works perfect.
Maybe i will help, if sameone have the same problem.